# finding volume of solid

Tags: calculus, volume

Suppose that a solid is formed in such a way that each cross section perpendicular to the x-axis, for $0 \le x \le 1$, is a disk, a diameter of which goes from the x-axis out to the curve $y = \sqrt{x}$.

Find the volume of the solid.

For this I use the disk formula. So $$\pi\displaystyle\int_0^1(\sqrt{x})^2\,dx.$$ When I do this, I get $\dfrac{\pi}5$. The answer is $\dfrac{\pi}8$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your answer seems correct. Are you sure about the $\frac{\pi}{8}$ answer ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe the book is wrong.

Comment: The radius is $\sqrt{x}/2$.

Comment: I messed up. I edited it. y didn't equal x^2. It equaled the sqrt(x). Which in this case, I get pi/2 for the volume.

Comment: But the radius is $\sqrt{x}/2$, since the diameter is $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: You are integrating wrong then. $\pi \int_0^1 (\sqrt{x})^2 \, dx $ should give $\pi/2$

Comment: Yes. I get pi/2. Not sure why the answer says it's pi/8.  I guess the book is not always right.

Comment: @Josh *diameter*. See my answer. It is a tricky question I think because usually it just gives you the function and the axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, and as well as @Soke pointed out, you are told that the cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are disks where the **diameter** is from $y=\sqrt{x}$ to $y=0$.

- The diameter of this disk is $\sqrt{x}$.
- The radius of this disk is $\sqrt{x}/2$.
- The cross-sectional area is $\pi (\sqrt{x}/2)^2$.
- $V = \int \text{"Cross-sectional Area"}\,\  d\text{ "axis perp to cross section"}$

$$V = \pi \int_0^1 \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^2\, dx = \pi\int_0^1 \dfrac{x}{4}\, dx = \left.\pi\dfrac{x^2}8\right|_0^1 = \dfrac\pi8$$

Answer (score 1):

You're doing two things wrong.

One, it is explicitly saying that the *diameter* of each shell is $\sqrt{x}$, so the radius would be $\sqrt{x} / 2$.

Next, you're integrating wrong. The integral you have ($ \pi \int \limits_0^1 (\sqrt{x})^2 \, dx$) should give $\pi / 2$ which, multiplied by the new $\frac{1}{4}$ from above, gives the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. But how did you get the radius to equal sqrt(x)/2?

Comment: @Josh The diameter is $\sqrt{x}$ and the radius is half of the diameter.